# ArgumentError: parent directory is world writable but not sticky (bundle install)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux

[Link to github for error printout](https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4599)

When i try to bundle install I receive the above error. I have tried what other posts suggest and the github community doesn't know the answer.

I am running Arch and am using zsh for my shell.

Updated Environment:

> Bundler   1.12.5
>
> Rubygems  2.5.1
>
> Ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768)[x86_64-linux]
>
> GEM_HOME  /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0
>
> GEM_PATH /usr/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0:/home/.gem/ruby/2.3.0
>
> Git       2.8.3
>
> open_gem (1.5.0)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `ls -l ~/.bundle/cache/compact_index/` and see the permissions.

Comment: The permission of the sub directories should be at most 1777 (`drwxrwxrwt`), which is world writable and sticky. BTW mine is 0755 (`drwxr-xr-x`).

Comment: I have tried modifying the permissions to no avail. the output of your ls is: 

drwxrwxrwx 1 rand 1000 8192 Jun  1 12:15 rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47

Comment: That's the problem. `drwxrwxrwx` (0777) means anyone can create/remove/move any file in that dir. `drwxrwxrwt` (1777, note the trailing `t`) means anyone can create file in that dir, but only the creator of that file can remove/move it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, run command

```
ls -l ~/.bundle/cache/compact_index/
```

You should see something like

```
drwxr-xr-x  3 myname  staff  102 Jun  1 23:03 rubygems.org.443.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

(I'm a miserable Chinese programmer so my folder is `ruby.taobao.org.443.07113fbafd9bf5f337f3f6cee4b3a723`. I guess the dir name is `<rubygems source domain>.<rubygems source port (443 for HTTPS)>.<checksum>`)

Pay attention to the `drwxr-xr-x` part, and make sure it's **NOT** `drwxrwxrwx`.

If it is `drwxrwxrwx`, then change it by the command

```
chmod 0755 rubygems.org.443.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

`drwxrwxrwx` (0777) means anyone can create any file in that dir (**world writable**) as well as remove/move them (**not sticky**). Bundler (>= 1.12.4) uses `compact_index` which in turn uses `Dir::mktmpdir` to create sub directories in that dir.

For security reason, the method `Dir::mktmpdir` verifies the permission of the parent dir of the to-be-created tmp dir. If the permission is 0777 (drwxrwxrwx) then you will see this error because it's insecure.

0755 (drwxr-xr-x) is fine because only the owner (user) of that directory can create/delete/move files or sub directories in that dir (not world writable). Anyone else can only list their information.

1777 (drwxrwxrwt) is also fine because anyone can create file or sub directory in that dir (world writable), but only the creator of that file can remove/move it (**sticky**).

Comment: Worked for me after I added the -R flag. So, my final command looked like this:

`chmod 0755 ~/.bundle/cache/compact_index/rubygems.org.443.29b0360b937aa4d161703e6160654e47 -R`

Comment: @mikedhart - Thanks, mine did not work without the -R switch

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

`chmod +t -R ~/.bundle/cache`

it works for me.

Comment: This worked for me on "Bash on Ubuntu" on Windows 10, too!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```
sudo chmod +t -R ~/.bundle/cache/compact_index/
```